# How enable and disable a button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, session

I'm new in this business and I would like to ask questions doubts about JavaScript and PHP

I am wanting to create a dynamic shop where by clicking the <kbd>View Details</kbd> will open the Modal and Within it there will be another button labelled <kbd>Choose</kbd> button. Clicking this <kbd>Choose</kbd> button appears an `alert("Do you want to choose this toy?")`. If accept the <kbd>Choose</kbd> button and the <kbd>View Details</kbd> will disabled (both named "Chosen").

And you will see a new button called <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button next to the <kbd>View Details</kbd>. Well, so far I  managed do the JavaScript.

My problem is:

I would like this JavaScript function to be "permanent" (even refreshing the page can not be changed JavaScript function "Disable"), but can only be changed if the user has disabled the function, click the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.

No other person with different login may cancel the function "disable" (ie, the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button will only be visible to Those Who clicked the <kbd>Select</kbd> button).

I would also like to store in The Following information database: (when the user chooses the product being Placed on a table, his name and the product he chose). Follow the code below with functional JavaScript function.

PHP:

[image: My PHP Code]

Script:

```
function Chosen() {
  if (confirm('Deseja escolher este brinquedo?')) {} else {
    exit;
  }

  document.getElementById('botaoE').value = 'Chosen';
  document.getElementById('botaoE').disabled = 'disabled';

  document.getElementById('botaoV').value = 'Chosen';
  document.getElementById('botaoV').disabled = 'disabled';

  document.getElementById('botaoC').style = 'display';
}

function Cancel() {
  if (confirm('Deseja cancelar este brinquedo?')) {} else {
    exit;
  }

  document.getElementById('botaoV').value = 'View Details';
  document.getElementById('botaoV').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.getElementById('botaoC').style = 'display:none';
}
```

HTML Body:

```
<div align="center">
  <div align="center">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="img-blocos img-responsive" src="img/brinquedo/carros.jpg" />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <div align="center">
      <!--Botão VER DETALHES-->
      <input type="button" id="botaoV" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCZ" value="View Details" />
      <!--Botão CANCELAR-->
      <input style="display:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="botaoC" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel();" />
    </div>

    <!--Modal-inicio-->
    <div id="myModalCZ" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="modal-title">MCQUEEN</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div align="center">Car 25cm.
              <br/>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/brinquedo/carros.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <!--Botão ESCOLHER-->
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botaoE" value="Choose" onclick="Chosen();" />
              <br/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal-Fim-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
document.getElementById('botaoV').disabled = 'disabled'
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('botaoV').disabled = true
```

Or you can also make your button like this:

```
onclick="Chosen(); this.disabled=true"
```

Try the following demo with no Server side language. It will work even after page refresh.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue; //We set our custom cookies here
}

function readCookie() {
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); //Cookies values separated by ; so we split them.
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) { //There can be more than one cookies
    var c = ca[i];
    if (c == 'status=disabled') { //if one of the cookies value match 'disabled'
      document.getElementById('botaoE').disabled = true; //We get botaoE and add disabled attribute
      document.getElementById('botaoC').style = 'display';
    } else {
      return ""; //If disabled is not found in our cookies, we return blank
    }
  }
}

function Chosen() {
  if (confirm('Confirm Chosen')) { //If you click on confirm prompt
    document.getElementById('botaoE').disabled = true; //id=botaoE will now have disabled attribute
    setCookie("status", 'disabled'); //We store the disable attribute in our cookie
    document.getElementById('botaoC').style = 'display'; // We show element with an id of botaoC
  } else {
    readCookie(); //If you click cancel on confirm prompt, we check the status of our cookie      
  }
}

function canCel() {
  if (confirm('Confirm Cancel?')) { //if you click OK on this confirm prompt
    var enabled = document.getElementById('botaoE').removeAttribute('disabled'); //We remove disabled attribute from an element with an id of botaoE
    document.getElementById('botaoC').style = 'none'; // And we hide an element with an id of botaoC
    setCookie("status", "");
  } else {
    return false; //Otherwise we return false, that means we don't do anything
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Removing and enabling disabled attribute</title>
</head>

<body onload="readCookie();">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botaoE" value="Choose" onclick="Chosen();">
  <input style="display:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="botaoC" value="Cancel" onclick="canCel();">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, the  function to disable the button works temporarily , if I do a page refresh, undo the function. It would be possible to leave this permanent disabled function ? (Type, if I click the " chose" even if refresh the page it will remain disabled.

Comment: you need to store the variable in session or database.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You must enable cookies in order to make it work.